# BeSimple SoapBundle receiving empty array

Tags: php, symfony, soap

I have Symfony with BeSimple SoapBundle. 
On the server the code looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Soap\Method("getUpdatedProducts")
 * @Soap\Param("data", phpType = "BeSimple\SoapCommon\Type\KeyValue\String[]")
 * @Soap\Result(phpType = "string")
 */
public function getUpdatedProductsAction (array $data) {
```

My client calls the function like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:9999/app_dev.php/ws/something?wsdl"); 

$response = $client->getUpdatedProducts(['test' => "1", "name" => "ivan"]);
```

The problem is that "$data" array that is received on the server is empty. When $data is string everything works fine, but not when it is associative array.

I am looking at their docs at http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/soapserver/tutorial/associative_array.html , but I can't figure it out.

What might be the problem ?